# Kubernetes Services Architecture

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-service

I'm trying to connect have NGINX direct traffic to different parts of my app through the config file, but I can't figure it out for the life of me. Here is my current setup:

```
  http-service (loadbalancer)
  NGINX (port 80)
  website-service (10.27.246.107, port 8000, targetPort 8000, selector 'run: website')
  website (label 'run: website', containerPort 8000)

  NGINX Conf
  upstream website{
    server 10.27.246.107:8000
  }
```

This is a normal nginx pod using containerPort 80 at the moment.

Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: Could you add more detail? are you using nginx ingress-controller or just nginx in pod with nodeport?

Comment: I updated the question, it's just a normal nginx pod with containerPort at the moment lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to rout traffic to different part of your application is using [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress). In Ingress, you can describe all your paths into all parts of your application. It will look like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo
        backend:
          serviceName: website1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /bar
        backend:
          serviceName: website2
          servicePort: 3368
```

Actually, Ingress-controller is based on Nginx, but anyway you can choose another engine, for example, HAproxy.
Ingress was designed for using in Kubernetes and it has more features in Kubernetes. For example, your website upstream should be described as a service in Kubernetes:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: website1
spec:
  selector:
    app: python-web-site
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
```

Anyway, you can route traffic by Nginx and expose it to the world, but the best practice is to uses Ingress in Kubernetes.

Comment: That makes more sense, thanks! I'll definitely try that

Comment: Just curious, does the http rule matter or have anything issues when using an https url? Lol

Comment: you can use HTTP or HTTP(s) the main different few additional rules for HTTP(s), where you explain the behavior of HTTP(s)